# Using statically resolved type parameters is it possible to call class method with curried arguments?

Tags: f#

```
type Test() =
    member t.A(a: int -> int) (b: int) = ()

let cl = Test()

let f a b =
    (^a : (member A: (int -> int) -> int -> unit) cl, a, b)
```

The above says that it cannot find the member or object contructor `A`. Is it possible to get the above to work somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no way to call it without changing its definition.
I'm not sure if it's in the spec but you can find that restriction in [the source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/ddfe73fe16190c5f0cb39f214080e6ac8bea2350/src/fsharp/ConstraintSolver.fs#L1231-L1233) where it filters out curried members.

Anyway if you want to use curried arguments you can use a lambda function and it will work:

```
type Test() =
    member t.A(a: int -> int) = fun (b: int) -> ()

let cl = Test()

let f a b =
    (^a : (member A: (int -> int) -> (int -> unit)) cl, a) b
```